# How to create/update drupal 6 CCK group fields for a specific content type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have following setup in Drupal 6:

Node Content Type: uprofile

Fields:
 field group: group_about with fields field_about_me, field_programinfo

I am creating a node using the following logic:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->title = trim($name);
$node->type = 'uprofile';
$node->created = time();
node_save($node);
```

I tried to save node using various methods, but all of them were futile, here is the one way I tried this(from drupal site):

```
$form_state = array();
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form_state['values']['type'] = 'uprofile';
$form_state['values']['status'] = 1;
$form_state['values']['op'] = t('Save');
$nodetype = array('type' => 'uprofile');
$form_state['values']['title'] = trim($name);
form_state['values']['field_about_me'][0]['value'] = trim($name);
$form_state['values']['field_programinfo'][0]['value'] = trim($name);
drupal_execute('uprofile_node_form', $form_state, (object)$nodetype);
```

This had no effect, and I am out of ideas on this. Can anyone please guide me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Been using something like this at one point to fetch and reformat data from other database and insert it into Drupal's:

```
$node = new StdClass();
$node->type = 'NODETYPE';
$node->status = 1;
$node->format = 2;
$node->moderate = 0;
$node->promote = 0;
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->revision = 0;
$node->comment = 0;
// Main node content
$node->title = 'TITLE';
$node->teaser = '';
$node->body = 'BODY';
// Author details
$node->uid = 1;
$node->name = 'USERNAME';
// CCK fields
$node->field_NODETYPE_summary[0]['value'] = 'SUMMARY';
$node->field_NODETYPE_details[0]['value'] = 'DETAILS';
// Submit and save
$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

Would need few amends to use in your specific case, but should give you something to start with.

Comment: I have changed this to
`$node = new StdClass();
$node->title = trim($name);
$node->type = 'uprofile';
$node->status = 1;
$node->uid = $org_user->uid;
$node->field_about_me[0]['value'] = trim($name);
`
That had no effect on setting the group field CCK value.

Any ideas?